# Insert all values from a table's column to another table's column in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables Roles and Menus and there is a relation on MenuId between these two tables. Both tables has relationship column with the same name "MenuId".

Menus has Primary Key and Roles has Foreign Key columns correspondingly.

I want to insert MenuId from Menus table to Roles Table using a loop, the Roles tables should have all the MenuId(s) from Menus table.

Something like as shown in below image.
RoleID 1 then all MenuID, then RoleId 2 and again all MenuID.

But I do not want insertion using triggers.

I have tried something like :-

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
WHILE @counter < 65 BEGIN
UPDATE Roles SET MenuId = @counter + 1
SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

[image]

Comment: you are trying to .update values in the query, and your question is *insert values*... it must be **update values in table**... right?

Comment: I have entered some records so want to update them 1st then want to insert new records, sorry for the confusion..

Comment: the problem with my query is that its hard-code( upto 65) but I want only values from the column(domain) only.

Answer (score 1):

To update existing `RoleId`s, you can use your method slightly modified:

```
DECLARE @counter int =0
DECLARE @records int

SELECT @records = COUNT(MenuId) FROM Menus

WHILE @counter < @records 
BEGIN

    UPDATE Roles SET MenuId = @counter + 1
    WHERE RoleId = 1
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

After that, if you want to insert each MenuId against every RoleId:
you can use "**INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...**" statement as,

```
DECLARE @roles int = 0

WHILE @roles < 10   --assuming that you have **10 roles** to insert
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Roles(MenuId, RoleId)
    SELECT MenuId, @roles --it's a roleId you want to insert
    FROM Menus m

    SET @roles = @roles + 1
END
```

Above query will **insert all MenuId against every RoleId**

Comment: update query updating the same value in all records.. and i have random values like 1,2,3,8,9,10 so it should be only these values..

Comment: update still has the same problem @Vikrant, and i think it should not be a hard code value in where clause of update command..

Comment: exactly, i also had the same hint

Answer (score 1):

create a 3rd table with the required columns and execute the below query on that table

```
insert into table3 (select table1.r_id,table2.menu_id from table1 cross join table2);
```

Comment: **want to insert MenuId from Menus table to Roles Table using a loop**, not required a third table

Answer (score 0):

The elephant in the room is doing things in a loop when working with SQL - performance is generally terrible and you almost never need to.

Not entirely clear on your db structure, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
create table Menu
(
    MenuId int 
);

create table Role 
(
    RoleId int
);

create table RoleMenu
(
    RoleId int,
    MenuId int
);

insert into Menu(MenuId) values(1),(2),(3);
insert into Role(RoleId) values(1),(2),(3),(4);

-- some data already in table
insert into RoleMenu(RoleId, MenuId) values(1,1), (1,2);

with cte as (
    select distinct RoleId, MenuId
    from Menu 
    cross join Role
)
insert into RoleMenu(RoleId, MenuId)
select cte.RoleId, cte.MenuId
from cte
left outer join RoleMenu rm on cte.MenuId = rm.MenuId and cte.RoleId = rm.RoleId 
where rm.RoleId is null -- don't insert where we already have data

select * from RoleMenu order by RoleId, MenuId
```